# Express Validator - If exists for nested array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, express-validator

```
{
    "orderId": "3",
    "storeId": "1",
    "products": [
         "productId": "123",
        {
         "prescriptions" : [{
            "eye": "1",
            "sph": "1",
            "cyl": "1",
            "add": "1",
            "axis": "1"
        }],
            "lensItems": {
                "lensId": "1",
                "lensType": "1",
                "lensCoating": "1",
                "index": "1",
                "price": "3000"
            },
            "frameSize": {
                "a": "1",
                "b": "1",
                "ed": "1",
                "fh": "1",
                "d": "2"
            },
            "counterSale": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to check the **prescriptions** only if the **lensItems** exists.

I have tried this,

```
 body('products.*.prescriptions')
        .if(body('products.*.lensItems').exists())
        .exists()
        .withMessage('prescriptions not exists')
        .isArray()
        .withMessage('prescriptions is not an array')
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage('prescriptions is empty'),
```

Its working when I check with `string` like below,

```
 body('products.*.prescriptions')
            .if(body('products.*.productId').exists())
            .exists()
            .withMessage('prescriptions not exists')
            .isArray()
            .withMessage('prescriptions is not an array')
            .notEmpty()
            .withMessage('prescriptions is empty'),
```

I want to the compare **array of object** with **object** . If any more regarding this please comment, I will share you much informations which are possible. Thanks in advance